# Codeigniter PHP framework error during using Model

Tags: php

I am using codeigniter php framework and I have faced with the following code during using Model in codeigniter so plz comment me how to solve it Thanks!

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in C:\wamp\www\codeigniter\CodeIgniter-3.1.10\application\models\My_model.php on line 6
>
> A PHP Error was encountered
>   Severity: Parsing Error
>
> Message: syntax error, unexpected '['
>
> Filename: models/My_model.php
>
> Line Number: 6
>
> Backtrace:

```
<?php
class My_model extends CI_Model{
    public function info()
    {
        return ["username" => "Nazir","Password" => "1122"];
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Which PHP version are you using? The short array syntax `[]` wasn't added until PHP 5.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using the older version of PHP.
You need to use array() to instantiate arrays in the older version of PHP:

```
class My_model extends CI_Model{
    public function info()
    {
        $result=array("username" => "Nazir","Password" => "1122");
        return $result;
    }
}
```